# Write to data lake in stream analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Is there a way that I can have a output to data lake from stream analytics and use a aad app or something else than my account that is used to write to data lake? It is not practical to have a user as the one that writes to the data lake.

Comment: Sid from the Stream Analytics team here. Can you please elaborate on your scenario - why isn't it practical to have a user that writes to the data lake? If you want to use another account to write to ADLS, then can you create SA jobs using that other account too?

Comment: If the stream analytics job runs on my account and the password needs to be renewed I have to refresh the authentication. Or if I leave the company my account will be deleted.

Wouldn't it be better that the job ran with a AAD application?

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I checked and tested [Azure Data Lake Store output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#azure-data-lake-store) for Azure Stream Analytics, and I found that this output would use my current account for authorization as you mentioned.

Moreover, as [Renew Data Lake Store authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#azure-data-lake-store) section mentioned as follows:

> Currently, there is a limitation where the authentication token needs to be manually refreshed **every 90 days** for all jobs with Data Lake Store output.

For your requirement, I assumed that you could add feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-stream-analytics). Or you could choose other outputs type for temporarily storing your results, then you could use another background task to trigger the temporary output store, then manually retrieve the records and write to your data lake. For this approach, you could leverage [Service-to-service authentication with Data Lake Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-net-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

For now answer is **No**

But it is planned to be available till the end of 2018

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-stream-analytics/suggestions/15367185-please-provide-support-for-azure-data-lake-store-o